# What type of spider is this? VA, USA

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Spider found in Richmond, VA. Can anyone identify?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, I can identify this for you!

That is an [Argiope Aurantia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argiope_aurantia), most commonly known as a "Yellow Garden Spider". They're quite well known for the design of the webs they spin, and because of this, they also go by "Sewing Spider" and "Writing Spider". They may try to bite if startled (which can be easy to do), but their venom is harmless to humans, so no worries.

[image: Argiope Aurantia1]

[image: Argiope Aurantia2]

[image: Cool Web Design]