# Which spider species is this, and is it dangerous?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Sorry for a quite bad picture. I was afraid to get closer!

Seen in Croatia, inlands, not near sea. As he is on the picture there with the legs stretched out, I'd say he was about 8-10 cm in length.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What type of spider is this? VA, USA](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64627/what-type-of-spider-is-this-va-usa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a female, the males of this genus are quite distinct. The genus is *Argiope*, and the specific epithet most probable is *bruennichi*. It is not a clinically important spider.